# how can I access my local web service from tizen emulator?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I'm a beginner in developping tizen tv apps and I was testing with simulator.
When I migrated to emulator, I couldn't access my local web service anymore.
The code worked just fine in simulator:

```js
var url="http://10.0.2.2/test/chaines.php"
    function loadDoc() {
 $.get(url, function(r){
  for (var i in r.result) {
    Ch_list.push({ 
              name: r.result[i].nom,
              id: r.result[i].id,
              url: r.result[i].url,
          });
  }
  })
}
```

I think this is a network problem, but I couldn't figure it out.

when I debug the project as a tizen web application, I get this message:
Detached from target:
Remote debugging has been terminatedwith reason: websocket_closed
Please re-attach to the new target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem of req. permission.
please check the usage from https://www.w3.org/TR/widgets-access/#usage-example.
according to the guide, access tag should be set in config.xml.
    `<access origin="http://example.org" subdomains="true"/>`
And check whether the Internet privilege is inserted in config.xml.

Comment: Thanks fo the answer. Actually, I already figure it out. Only the access tag is needed, there is no internet privilege when working on TV projects..